# Aircraft clip in the intro to the Six Million Dollar Man

Tags: the-six-million-dollar-man

In the intro of the 1970s TV show, "[The Six Million Dollar Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six_Million_Dollar_Man)" there is an experimental delta aircraft shown under the wing of a B-52 Stratofortress:

[image]

This is the test aircraft in which the main character, astronaut Steve Austin, crashes.

Is this just a special effects clip done with models, or is it based on footage of a real test aircraft?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The plane was a Northrop M2-F2 according to [IMdb Six Million Dollar Man Trivia section](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071054/trivia?item=tr0771007)

> The aircraft seen crashing in the show's opening sequence was an M2-F2, a "lifting body configuration" built by Northrop. The audio sound effects are from a crash that occurred on May 10, 1967, at Edwards Air Force base in California (although the dialogue heard was recorded by Lee Majors). The test pilot, Bruce Peterson, hit the ground at two hundred fifty miles per hour, tumbling six times. He lost use of his right eye following an infection, and had to stop flying, ending his career. Understandably, Peterson has said that he hated reliving his accident, week after week, courtesy of the show.

Here's a video explaining the crash and it's use in the opening sequence of the show.